# How can a create a folder and save a image on my server in php?

Tags: php

Below I have left my code. It currently works in my development environment (localhost), but when I push the changes to my live server it seems like my php doesn't create the folder/file.

```
public static function saveImage($image, $name, $path = '')
{
    $img_data = explode(',', $image);
    $mime = explode(';', $img_data[0]);
    $data = $img_data[1];
    $extension = explode('/', $mime[0])[1];
    if(!file_exists('../public/media/img/' . $path)){
        mkdir('../public/media/img/' . $path, 0755);
        echo('Test1');
    }
    echo('test2');
    file_put_contents('../public/media/img/' . $path . $name . '.' . $extension, base64_decode($data));
    return 'media/img/' . $path . $name . '.' . $extension;
}
```

Locally it will hit echo('test1') the first time, then it will only hit echo('test2'). When its on the server it always hits the echo('test1')

Comment: You might not have sufficient read/write rights on the server to actually create the folder. In that case the script will retry creating the folder every time failing silently. Try checking the return value from mkdir for file1 or check on the server if the folder actually got created

Comment: @Hafenkranich It never does get created, it returns a boolean with the value of false. How can i set permissions on my server?

Comment: if you do have sufficient rights and a ssh connection you can do `chmod -R 664 mywebfolder/public/media/img/` that should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

By default mkdir is not create a path recursively. An example if on your server you dont have a ../public/media  folder, mkdir returns false and dont create a path.
To solve this pass a third parameter to mkdir as true:

```php
mkdir('../public/media/img/' . $path, 0755, true);
```

Comment: The server does have a public/media folder. Like i said it works locally but on the production server it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favour and use absolute pathes...

You can use the constant `__DIR__` to evaluate the folder in which the script actually resides. 
Relative pathes are calculated from the current working directory, which can be different than `__DIR__`

Comment: The relative path works fine locally. It creates and saves files like its intended too. Just when it is on the production server it doesn't work.

Comment: Compare the outputs of this code on dev/live environments `var_dump(realpath(__DIR__ . '/../public/media/img/'), realpath('../public/media/img/'));`

Comment: /../ returns as a bool on both dev/production. ../public... both have different paths but both end with public/media/img